# How to force Mail to use Mail Drop on attachment smaller than 20MB

Tags: macos, email, osx-yosemite

The recipient of an email message I composed has a maximum message size of 10MB. I am trying to send an attachment that is 15MB. Mail on Yosemite does not use Mail Drop unless the message is about 20MB or more. The message is being returned by the receiver's mail system because the message is 15MB and it exceeds their maximum of 10MB.

Is there a way, a user default maybe that can be entered in the Terminal app to force Mail on Yosemite to send my message using Mail Drop?

It would be nice if Mail on Yosemite recognized the email being returned and prompt you for a chance to resend using Mail Drop.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow.  Please read the FAQ for information on what questions are on-topic.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem and just read in http://www.macrumors.com/2014/10/17/yosemite-markup-and-mail-drop/ that there is not much that can be done, so I have used a small cheat: I have put in one folder the attachment together with a very large "dummy" file to trigger MailDrop. I know, not the best way to go about this but it worked for me.

The steps:

1. Take a screenshot of any part of your desktop with cmd+ctrl-shift+4
2. Open Preview
3. Hit cmd+n to paste in a new document
4. in Preview:
   a.  Open the tool box
   b.  Select the change size icon
   c.  Increase the resolution until 
   d.  You get the file size to go above 30MB
5. Hit OK, save this file, put it in a folder together with the file you want to send, zip it up and send.

Again, not the best path but the only one I found so far.

Answer (score -3):

Include multiple copies of the same attachment until you reach 20 MB