# Mail Drop below 20mb

Tags: ios, iphone, email, exchange-server

I have an App that sends a PDF file via the share sheet. I've been having reports that the outgoing mail sometimes gets stuck in the Outbox.

This seems to occur when the attachment is above ~7MB and for Exchange servers only. This seems [consistent](https://serverfault.com/questions/697284/email-from-ios-with-attachments-larger-than-7-5mb-gets-stuck-in-outbox-and-const) with problems other people have been facing. Mail Drop works as normal.

So I'm stuck in limbo here, if the PDF is greater than 7.5MB but less than 20MB, then there doesn't appear to be a way to email the file. It also appears that there isn't away to use [Mail Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949078/how-to-force-mail-to-use-mail-drop-on-attachment-smaller-than-20mb) below 20MB.

Does anyone have an alternative suggestion to sending this email?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should upload the file on a server (maybe your own server, maybe on something like dropbox) and then share the link in the email if the file size exceeds 7mb.